# how to add textbox dynamically and save in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add textboxes dynamically and save these values to database in asp.net, Is there any controls for this in asp.net?

how can I do this in asp.net?

Comment: I know this can be done using jquery, but after a postback the new textboxes will be lost

Comment: I can help you in maintaing that state ,if you can provide code in jquery or else this can be done using the Panel, which i will share that as answer

Comment: Check this: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-Insert-dynamic-TextBox-Value-Text-to-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 4):

To add dynamic control in your .aspx file below is sample code.

Add below div in your .aspx file with id which is addControl

```
<div id="addControl" runat="server">
</div>
```

You can create dynamic TextBox control by adding below code in you .cs file.
Add Control is a id of above define div.

```
 TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
 txt1.ID = "txtOne";
 txt1.Text = "";
 txt1.CssClass = "myClass";
 txt1.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
 addControl.Controls.Add(txt1);
```

With the help of NameValueCollection you can get the value of TextBox.

```
NameValueCollection frmCollection = Request.Form;
string inputString = frmCollection["txtOne"];
```

> NameValueCollection represents a collection of associated String keys
>   and String values that can be accessed either with the key or with the
>   index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Panel** to create the Dynamic Text box. Panel pnlTextBox;

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create a Dynamic Panel
    pnlTextBox = new Panel();
    pnlTextBox.ID = "pnlTextBox";
    pnlTextBox.BorderWidth = 1;
    pnlTextBox.Width = 300;
    this.form1.Controls.Add(pnlTextBox);

    //Create a LinkDynamic Button to Add TextBoxes
    LinkButton btnAddtxt = new LinkButton();
    btnAddtxt.ID = "btnAddTxt";
    btnAddtxt.Text = "Add TextBox";
    btnAddtxt.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
    this.form1.Controls.Add(btnAddtxt);

    //Recreate Controls
    RecreateControls("txtDynamic", "TextBox");
}
```

For saving to DB:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Save" />
```

**C#**

protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Names(Name) VALUES(@Name)"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtDynamic.Text);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

}
```

For More details please refer [this link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-Insert-dynamic-TextBox-Value-Text-to-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

**Edit**

As you mentioned in your Comments that you are using Jquery  , so in order to load that during the postbacks try to load the Textbox in

```
function pageLoad() {// your dynamic Text box code using Jquery}
```